# Layout of Node.js Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-structure

I'm new to Node.js and am unsure about how to layout some things.

My directory structure is as follows (I'm open to changing this):

```
- controllers 
- helpers 
- middlewares 
- models 
    - BlockLibraryConfigs.js
    - BlockMosaicStreamer.js
    - GlobalMercator.js 
    - index.js 
    - MosaicStreamer.js
- nbproject 
    - private 
        - private.properties
        - private.xml
    - project.properties 
    - project.xml
- node_modules
    - all installed modules . . . 
- public 
    - images 
    - javascripts 
    - stylesheets 
        - style.css
- tests 
- views 
    - index.jade 
    - layout.jade 
    - view.jade
app.js 
package.json
```

The files under models, with the exception of `index.js` include classes. Is this the right spot for them? If so, I should make them accessible through `index.js`, right? What's the proper way to go about this?

Comment: This is a highly subjective topic (and may run counter to Stack Overflow's [Good question criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).) That said, I've always put source files in a `./src/` folder and then split it up in whatever way makes the most sense for me there.

Comment: did you try using the express generator? it'll create a skeleton app for you that you can build from. http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly reasonable layout keeping in mind that there isn't no one true way. You can either manually have your models/index.js include and export them, or just use `require-directory` from NPM. Obviously as your project grows in complexity your layout may get more complex as you divide up views and your javascript folder.

Also note that the plural of middleware is still just middleware, likewise for javascript.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to manually export the models in `index.js`?

Comment: module.exports = {
  MosiacStreamer: require('./MosiacStreamer.js'),
  ...
};